# Why does '[:print:][:blank:]' become 'in' if a file 'in' exists in the current directory?

Tags: shell

Is this normal? I tried it (long story... it all began with poor quoting on something else) with bash, dash and ksh. In all cases I get:

```
$ echo [:print:][:blank:]
[:print:][:blank:]
$ touch in
$ echo [:print:][:blank:]
in
```

I thought it had something to do with 'in' being a substring of 'print', but (say) 'pr' doesn't do it:

```
$ rm in; touch pr
$ echo [:print:][:blank:]
[:print:][:blank:]
```

Also, dropping 'blank' gets rid of this:

```
$ touch in; echo [:print:]         
[:print:]
```

I am completely lost. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want to print the literal string "[:print:][:blank:]", enclose it in single quotes so none of the [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) occur.

Comment: Well, that was embarrasing... Thanks to all for the answers and pointers. I'm (evidently!) not a shell guru, but I have used quite a few times in the past things such as `ls [aeiou]`?... Just for reference, the relevant POSIX explanation [can be found here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03). @glenn jackman: Indeed, all this happened because I tried to outsmart myself by using 'minimal quoting'... In this case I believe double quotes would also work, such as `echo "*"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[:print:][:blank:]` is regarded as a glob pattern, so any filenames matching it will be printed, just like when you say `echo *` (try that in an empty directory).

`[:print:]` is interpreted as "one of the characters {`:`,`p`,`r`,`i`,`n`,`t`}" and similarly for `[:blank:]`; hence the match with `in`, but not `pr`.

(`pr` will match `[:print:][:print:]`, though.)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the shell performs **pathname expansion** and replaces the pattern `[:print:][:blank:]` with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern. If no matching file names are found, the word is left unchanged. So, if your directory contains a file called `in` it is picked up because it matches the pattern.

Similarly, if you had files called `pb`, `ta` etc, they too would be picked up. However, `pr` does not match the pattern.

These file names are then passed to `echo` and are printed on screen.

For more information, see the [bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion).